# Trying to create this. Can someone assist?

Tags: javascript, object, key, counter, optional-arguments

Can someone assist with this query below?

In JavaScript, define a function `makeCounter` which takes one optional argument defining the intial value, `start`, with a default value of 0. The function should return an object containing keys that define 3 methods:
- `value` returns the current value of the counter
- `increment` increments the value of the counter by 1 and returns the new value
- `decrement` decrements the value of the counter by 1 and returns the new value

```
The returned object should not allow direct modification or retrieval of the value.


Example usage:

var counter = makeCounter();
console.log(counter.value());
// 0

var counter2 = makeCounter(4);

console.log(counter2.value());
// 4

console.log(counter2.increment());
// 5
console.log(counter2.value());
// 5

counter2.decrement();
counter2.decrement();
console.log(counter2.decrement());
// 2
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Which part of your code are you having problems with? You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [mcve]. [Here's a question checklist you might find useful.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822). Just copy/pasting your assignments will not win you any friends.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using a function `makeCounter()`, I suggest just using the `new` operator. The `#` prefix to the `value` class field makes it private.

```js
class Counter {
  #value
  constructor(value = 0) {
    this.#value = value;
  }
  value() {
    return this.#value;
  }
  increment() {
    this.#value++;
  }
  decrement() {
    this.#value--;
  }
}

let counter = new Counter(3);
console.log(counter.value());
counter.increment();
console.log(counter.value());
```

Comment: *"Instead of using a function `makeCounter()`, I suggest just using the `new` operator"* why? I don't see the point in introducing concepts like classes and private fields into this.

Comment: @Thomas Regarding classes, because the alternative (i.e. `makeX()` functions constructing object literals containing methods) is frowned upon. Regarding private fields, because the question explicitly asks that the field not be publicly accessible.